# Evernote API: AttributeError: 'Store' object has no attribute 'getNoteWithResultSpec'

Tags: api, evernote

I tried to use the method '**getNoteWithResultSpec**' (doc: https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getNoteWithResultSpec). I get AttributeError: 'Store' object has no attribute 'getNoteWithResultSpec'. Many other methods (e.g. getNote, findNotesMetadata etc.) just work fine for me. Any suggestions for a solution? Thanks.

I made a mistake and used **NotesMetadataResultSpec** instead of **NoteResultSpec**
But when I want to import **NoteResultSpec** (from evernote.edam.notestore.ttypes import NoteResultSpec) I get an import error.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately at time of writing, the documentation and the code in the github repo does not match the implementation that is installed via PIP.  The `getNoteWithResultSpec` call is not available yet, I presume it is a recent addition.  If you do the following you can find where your evernote library is located in your filesystem and so you can then see what it is actually available:

```
> import evernote
> evernote.__file__
```